# Swift: Image losing aspect ratio when drawing starts

Tags: swift

I am attempting to make an image editing VC for my app and encountered the above issue. Whenever I start drawing on my image, the image would warp and then lose the aspect ratio.

Gif is:

[image]

My full code is:

```
class DrawImageController: UIViewController {
    
    var canvasImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return iv
    }()
    
    var lastTouch = CGPoint.zero
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = .black

        view.addSubview(canvasImageView)
        
        canvasImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        canvasImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        canvasImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        canvasImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        
        canvasImageView.image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let firstTouch = touches.first {
            lastTouch = firstTouch.location(in: canvasImageView)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let firstTouch = touches.first {
            let touchLocation = firstTouch.location(in: canvasImageView)
            drawLine(from: lastTouch, to: touchLocation)
            lastTouch = touchLocation
        }
    }

    func drawLine(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvasImageView.frame.size)
        
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            canvasImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: canvasImageView.frame.size.width, height: canvasImageView.frame.size.height))

            context.move(to: from)
            context.addLine(to: to)
            
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.setLineWidth(5.0)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
            
            context.strokePath()
            
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            canvasImageView.image = image
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }          
    }
}
```

I adapted my draw method from various tutorials on YouTube, GitHub and SO. Where have I gone wrong?

### Solved

With the advice from @Sweeper, I have modified my code in `setupViews()` and `drawLine` to account for aspect ratio of the image and imageView.

```
func setupViews() {
    view.backgroundColor = .black

    view.addSubview(canvasImageView)
    
    canvasImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let aspectRatio = getImageAspectRatio(image: UIImage(named: "testImage")!)
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let height = CGFloat(1.0) / aspectRatio * screenWidth
    canvasImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true

    canvasImageView.image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
}

func drawLine(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvasImageView.frame.size)
    
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return}
    
    if let canvasImage = canvasImageView.image {
        let imageViewAspectRatio = getAspectRatio(frame: canvasImageView.frame)
        let imageAspectRatio = getImageAspectRatio(image: canvasImage)
        
        if imageViewAspectRatio > imageAspectRatio {
            canvasImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageAspectRatio * canvasImageView.frame.size.height, height: canvasImageView.frame.size.height))
        } else if imageViewAspectRatio < imageAspectRatio {
            canvasImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: canvasImageView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(1.0) / imageAspectRatio * canvasImageView.frame.size.width))
        } else {
            canvasImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: canvasImageView.frame.size.width, height: canvasImageView.frame.size.height))
        }
        
        context.move(to: from)
        context.addLine(to: to)
        
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.setLineWidth(5.0)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        
        context.strokePath()
        
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        canvasImageView.image = image
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
canvasImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: canvasImageView.frame.size.width, height: canvasImageView.frame.size.height))
```

You are drawing the image using the image view's frame. *This stretches the image.*

You need to draw the image *as if* `contentMode` is `.scaleAspectFit`.

To do this, first determine the image's aspect ratio (W:H). You can do this by access the `size` property of `UIImage`. Compare this ratio to the aspect ratio of the image view.

If the image's ratio is smaller than the view's, then that means the height at which you draw the image can be the same as the image view height, and the image width can be calculated using the aspect ratio of the image.

If the image's ratio is larger than the view's, then that means the width at which you draw the image can be the same as the image view width, and the image height can be calculated,

Comment: thanks! Your advice worked. I will mark this as my answer and will update my code in my question above to help ppl in future.