# Swift: Retain floating point decimal in autolayout

Tags: swift

this is a follow on question from my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134090/swift-image-losing-aspect-ratio-when-drawing-starts). I am attempting to fix my heightConstraint of imageView dynamically depending on the size of my image, and then add a drawing layer over it. However, I noticed that the imageView size loses precision due to the division of floating point and this resulted in a blurred image when I start to draw on my image, ie the placement of the bitmap is not exactly at the position overlaying my original image.

My code as such, with the print statements to observe the decimal places.

```
func setupViews() {
    view.backgroundColor = .black

    view.addSubview(canvasImageView)

    canvasImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    let aspectRatio = getImageAspectRatio(image: image)
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let height = CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(aspectRatio)  * CGFloat(screenWidth)
    canvasImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    print("ImageSize", image.size.height)
    print("Aspect Ratio image at start:", aspectRatio)
    print("Calculated height:", height)


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Aspect Ratio imageView at start:", self.getAspectRatio(frame: self.canvasImageView.frame))
        print("ImageViewSize", self.canvasImageView.frame.height)

    }
}
```

My print statements are here:

```
ImageSize 3000.0 2002.0  
Aspect Ratio image at start: 1.4985014985015 
Calculated height: 213.546666666667  
Aspect Ratio imageView at start: 1.49532710280374  
ImageViewSize 320.0 214.0
```

As you can see, my attempt to do the  `heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)` actually loses the precision and resulting in a lost of resolution. Is there a way to eliminate this? An image of the outcome is here.

[image]